# Drop down menu of paths using rails 'select' method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

From this [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html) I see that I can use the select method like this:

```
select("post", "person_id", Person.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, { :include_blank => true })
```

and it yields:

```
<select name="post[person_id]">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1" selected="selected">David</option>
  <option value="2">Sam</option>
  <option value="3">Tobias</option>
</select>
```

What would my select method look like if I have an array like this:

```
[["Add Post", new_post_path],["Add Document", new_document_path],["Add Coupon", new_coupon_path]]
```

And I want html like this:

```
<select name="post[person_id]">
  <option value="new_post_path" selected="selected">Add Post</option>
  <option value="new_document_path">Add Document</option>
  <option value="new_coupon_path">Add Coupon</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller:

```
@paths = [ ["Add Post", new_post_url], ["Add Document", new_document_url], ... ]
```

In your view

```
select("post", "person_id", @paths, { :include_blank => true })
```

This should put the actual URL in the value field. If you want the strings as you noted above, but the paths in quotes, e.g. `["Add Post", "new_post_path"]`